# VSCode Debug a single test without running all other tests under a CMake target

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

I am learning the leveldb source code and trying to debug the `filter_block_test` [test](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/main/table/filter_block_test.cc). The CMake project is imported into VSCode and have multiple targets generated. One of the target [`leveldbtests`](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt#L328) contains the test file I want to debug.

I am able to setup the CMake debugger and get it running but the problem is the debugger needs to run through all the tests preceding the `filter_block_test` defined under the `leveldbtests` target before it enters the debugging part of `filter_block_test` so I have to wait all the preceding tests done to debug the single test file. Is there a way to debug the desired file/files without running all the preceding tests defined under the same target?

Comment: Ugly, but perhaps you will have to resort to commenting out the earlier tests unless they're a pre-requisite? Running and debugging code is really not VS Code's forte.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am using mac which does not have visual studio code so I have to fall back to VS code + third party plugins. But would like to know if you have any recommendation

Comment: @dashenswen You absolutely do not have to "fall back" to VSCode. You can use *any* text editor - like notepad, vim, Emacs or *whatever* to write C++ code and then hand it to a compiler from the command line.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am new to c++ and only have experience to run compiler to link files/build executable. I need the features including quick code search/jumping between files for references/debug.. I am not sure if all these can be done in any text editor like vim or notepad.